# Convert numbers to strings in a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

I have a cell array with numbers and string data. I need to convert the numbers to strings so that I can use the `unique()` function.

```
a = {1; 4; 'lf'}
result --> {'1', '4', 'lf'}; % Now unique() function can be used
```

There are online solutions to handle a case where the column was numerical.  But those cannot be used here as at least 1 row has string as data. A vectorized solution shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Use `cellfun()` for applying `num2str()` to every cell element:

```
result = cellfun(@num2str, a, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

This (with `UniformOutput` set to `false`) will automatically handle the non-scalar, char elements of the array.